# Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information

Tags: react-native, expo, build.gradle, gradlew, eas

> Task :expo-splash-screen:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED

[stderr]

e: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-splash-screen/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/splashscreen/SplashScreenReactActivityLifecycleListener.kt:16:3 'onContentChanged' overrides nothing

> Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets

info Writing bundle output to:, /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle

info Writing sourcemap output to:, /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/intermediates/sourcemaps/react/release/index.android.bundle.packager.map

info Done writing bundle output

info Done writing sourcemap output

info Copying 25 asset files

info Done copying assets

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:2728:18: warning: the variable "DebuggerInternal" was not declared in function "__shouldPauseOnThrow"

[stderr]

```
      typeof DebuggerInternal !== 'undefined' &&
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:11514:7: warning: the variable "setTimeout" was not declared in function "logCapturedError"

[stderr]

```
  setTimeout(function () {
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle

[stderr]

:9474:108: warning: the variable "nativeFabricUIManager" was not declared in function "onChange"

[stderr]

...lInstanceHandle ? (from && nativeFabricUIManager.setIsJSResponder(from.sta...

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:10095:21: warning: the variable "clearTimeout" was not declared in anonymous function " 264#"

[stderr]

```
cancelTimeout = clearTimeout;
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:13845:30: warning: the variable "**REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK**" was not declared in anonymous function " 264#"

[stderr]

if ("undefined" !== typeof **REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK**) {

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:15730:5: warning: the variable "setImmediate" was not declared in function "handleResolved"

[stderr]

```
setImmediate(function () {
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19906:12: warning: the variable "fetch" was not declared in anonymous function " 499#"

[stderr]

```
fetch: fetch,
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19907:14: warning: the variable "Headers" was not declared in anonymous function " 499#"

[stderr]

```
Headers: Headers,
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19908:14: warning: the variable "Request" was not declared in anonymous function " 499#"

[stderr]

```
Request: Request,
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19909:15: warning: the variable "Response" was not declared in anonymous function " 499#"

[stderr]

```
Response: Response
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20066:24: warning: the variable "FileReader" was not declared in function "readBlobAsArrayBuffer"

[stderr]

```
  var reader = new FileReader();
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:

[stderr]

20117:36: warning: the variable "Blob" was not declared in anonymous function " 510#"

[stderr]

```
    } else if (support.blob && Blob.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20119:40: warning: the variable "FormData" was not declared in anonymous function " 510#"

[stderr]

```
    } else if (support.formData && FormData.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20121:44: warning: the variable "URLSearchParams" was not declared in anonymous function " 510#"

[stderr]

...e if (support.searchParams && URLSearchParams.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body...

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20240:26: warning: the variable "AbortController" was not declared in anonymous function " 516#"

[stderr]

```
      var ctrl = new AbortController();
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20373:23: warning: the variable "XMLHttpRequest" was not declared in anonymous function " 520#"

[stderr]

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19919:71: warning: the variable "self" was not declared in anonymous function " 502#"

[stderr]

...undefined' && globalThis || typeof self !== 'undefined' && self ||

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:23870:27: warning: the variable "performance" was not declared in anonymous function " 670#"

[stderr]

if ("object" === typeof performance && "function" === typeof performance.no...

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:23893:26: warning: the variable "navigator" was not declared in anonymous function " 670#"

[stderr]

"undefined" !== typeof navigator && undefined !== navigator.scheduling && u...

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:24003:37: warning: the variable "MessageChannel" was not declared in anonymous function " 670#"

[stderr]

};else if ("undefined" !== typeof MessageChannel) {

[stderr]

```
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:24018:34: warning: the variable "nativeRuntimeScheduler" was not declared in anonymous function " 670#"

[stderr]

... = "undefined" !== typeof nativeRuntimeScheduler ? nativeRuntimeScheduler....

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:36720:34: warning: the variable "requestAnimationFrame" was not declared in function "start 9#"

[stderr]

...    this._animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(this.onUpdate.bind(this));

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle

[stderr]

:70072:20: warning: the variable "localStorage" was not declared in function "ColorSchemeStore"

[stderr]

if (typeof localStorage !== "undefined") {

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:75070:29: warning: the variable "IDBDatabase" was not declared in function "getMethod"

[stderr]

```
if (!(target instanceof IDBDatabase && !(prop in target) && typeof prop =...
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:75079:37: warning: the variable "IDBIndex" was not declared in function "getMethod"

[stderr]

```
!(targetFuncName in (useIndex ? IDBIndex : IDBObjectStore).prototype) || ...
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:75079:48: warning: the variable "IDBObjectStore" was not declared in function "getMethod"

[stderr]

...ame in (useIndex ? IDBIndex : IDBObjectStore).prototype) || !(isWrite || r...

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:75133:94: warning: the variable "IDBCursor" was not declared in function "getIdbProxyableTypes"

[stderr]

...abase, IDBObjectStore, IDBIndex, IDBCursor, IDBTransaction]);

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:75133:105: warning:

[stderr]

the variable "IDBTransaction" was not declared in function "getIdbProxyableTypes"

[stderr]

...ctStore, IDBIndex, IDBCursor, IDBTransaction]);

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:75188:32: warning: the variable "DOMException" was not declared in function "error 2#"

[stderr]

```
    reject(tx.error || new DOMException('AbortError', 'AbortError'));
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:75280:26: warning: the variable "IDBRequest" was not declared in function "wrap 1#"

[stderr]

```
if (value instanceof IDBRequest) return promisifyRequest(value);
```

> Task :expo-file-system:compileReleaseKotlin

> Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[x86_64]

w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

299 actionable tasks: 299 executed

[stderr]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

[stderr]

- What went wrong:

[stderr]

Execution failed for task ':expo-splash-screen:compileReleaseKotlin'.

[stderr]

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction

[stderr]

> Compilation error. See log for more details

[stderr]

- Try:

[stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr]

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr]

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr]

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

[stderr]

BUILD FAILED in 5m 41s

Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

Comment: Please, reformat your question and put the output in the "code sample" section. And describe your problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Habe u find solution for that error?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error appears after the version of `"expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5"` version. You should check `expo-splash-screen` [related issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/23801). Try to upgrade `expo` to [~49.0.6](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1965#issuecomment-1660795254)

```
Execution failed for task ':expo-splash-screen:compileReleaseKotlin'.
```